# Can you integrate SSIS project with website?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

According to my project requirements, I need to develop a few pages on the company website where the user would upload an excel sheet to transfer the data to MS SQL Server. I am getting started with SSIS but I want to know how to make this part of a web page.

Comment: So you're a fan of [big-endians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliput_and_Blefuscu)...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use SSIS package in web applications. Also processing Excel file inside your application might be complecated so, one common approach for this problem is:

1. Store uploaded document in a specific folder.
2. Name the files using a timestamp like (F2020_05_29_10:330:24_3283) or any other methods to make them unique
3. Deploy your SSIS package to SQL Server and schedule a job to run the package
4. In your package look into that specific folder to see if there is any new incoming file.
5. If there is one or more files, process them inside your SSIS package

Another way is processing your Excel file using COM Interop or using OpenXML which might be complicated.

Comment: No need to schedule the job. After the user uploads the file, simply call the job as any other database query `EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'ExcelWebProcessor'`

Comment: Good approach. Other point I'd caution on is that the Excel COM Interop approach will require an Office license on the web server - consult with your licensed authorized reseller to confirm

Comment: Right. That's part of complication. Usually companies do not allow install office on server because of security.

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule the SSIS in a sql job to run every few minutes or so.  Use a for each loop so that it doesn't actually do anything if there is not file.

Comment: As I said, I want it to be a part of the website. I don't want to schedule anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you probably don't want to.

Excel and SSIS are finicky bedfellows at best. SSIS believes in a firm set of metadata being established a design time and adhered to at runtime. Excel interprets metadata based on sampling the first 8 rows of data. If the Excel file is machine generated, then SSIS and it can work together fine enough but since this will be users uploading files... you're going to spend a lot of time troubleshooting why two seemingly identical spreadsheets won't parse the same way in SSIS.

How do you get SSIS to run? Either you use the object model or use dtexec.exe to make it go. Both of those approaches are only valid if you have licensed the server for SQL Server. If you install the object library or the Integration Services Service on your web server, you will need to buy another SQL Server license for your enterprise. That's expensive.

What I, probably the person most in love with SSIS on Stack Overflow do? I'd use an OpenXml library, like EPPlus. I blogged about an approach in [Reading Excel files without Excel](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2018/10/reading-excel-files-without-excel.html)

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
// ...
/// Get data from Excel worksheet, assuming columns A-G are desired
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetExcelDriverData(string sourceFile)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(sourceFile);
    using (ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        ExcelWorkbook wb = ep.Workbook;
        ExcelWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.First();
        if (ws != null)
        {
            // 1 based array to 7, inclusive
            for (int i = ws.Dimension.Start.Row+1; i < ws.Dimension.End.Row+1; i++)
            {
                List<string> row = new List<string>() { ws.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString()
                ,   ws.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString()
                ,   ws.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString()
                ,   ws.Cells[i, 4].Value.ToString()
                ,   ws.Cells[i, 5].Value.ToString()
                ,   ws.Cells[i, 6].Value.ToString()
                ,   ws.Cells[i, 7].Value.ToString()
                };

                d[ws.Cells[i, 7].Value.ToString()] = row;
            }
        }
    }

    return d;
}
```

Note that this is the [last LGPL version of EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) if you're nuget'ing things. Version 5+ requires licensing but it's far cheaper than a SQL Server license.